# Como llenar 2 selects dependientes desde la base de datos en php y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta para llenar 2 selects desde la base de datos, necesito que si el usuario selecciona el nombre de una academia entonces se introduzca en la bd los datos del usuario, el nombre de la academia seleccionada y el id de la academia que seleccionó.

El formulario se ve de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el model únicamente llamo al Storage Procedure que selecciona esos valores

```
function MostrarAcademias(){

    $instancia = AbrirBaseDatos();

    $listaAcademia = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_ACADEMIA_SELECT();");

    CerrarBaseDatos($instancia);

    return $listaAcademia;
}
```

Por el momento estoy llenando los select de esta forma desde el controlador

```
function LlenarSelectAcademia(){
    $listaAcademia = MostrarAcademias();

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($listaAcademia)){
        echo 
        '
          <option value="'. $item['NOMBRE_ACA'] .'">'. $item['NOMBRE_ACA'] .'</option>
        ';
    }
}

function LlenarSelectAcademiaId(){
  $listaAcademia = MostrarAcademias();

  while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($listaAcademia)){
      echo 
      '
        <option value="'. $item['ID_ACA'] .'"></option>
      ';
  }
}
```

Y en la vista lo hago de esta forma

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    <select name="txtIdAcademia" class="form-control" REQUIRED>
        <?php LlenarSelectAcademiaId();?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Nombre Academia</label>
    <select name="txtNomAcademia" class="form-control" REQUIRED>
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php LlenarSelectAcademia();?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Es importante mencionar que el procedimiento almacenado que inserta esos datos a la base de datos se ve así

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_PROFESOR_INSERTAR(
ID_ACADEMIA INT,
NOMBRE_PROF VARCHAR(60),
NUM_TEL_PROF VARCHAR(30),
CEDULA_PROF VARCHAR(20),
EMAIL_PROF VARCHAR(100),
NOM_ACADEMIA VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO PROFESOR(ID_ACADEMIA, NOMBRE_PROF, NUM_TEL_PROF, CEDULA_PROF, EMAIL_PROF, NOM_ACADEMIA) VALUES (ID_ACADEMIA, NOMBRE_PROF, NUM_TEL_PROF, CEDULA_PROF, EMAIL_PROF, NOM_ACADEMIA);
END//
```

Y también el model que se encarga de insertar los datos en la aplicación de PHP luce así:

```
function RegistrarProfesorModel(){
    $instancia = AbrirBaseDatos();

    if(!empty($_POST["btnRegistrarProfesor"])){
        if(!empty($_POST["txtNombre"]) and !empty($_POST["txtNumTel"]) and !empty($_POST["txtCedula"]) and !empty($_POST["txtCorreo"]) and !empty($_POST["txtNomAcademia"])){
            $nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"];
            $numTel = $_POST["txtNumTel"];
            $cedula = $_POST["txtCedula"];
            $correo = $_POST["txtCorreo"];
            $idAcademia = $_POST["txtIdAcademia"];
            $nomAcademia = $_POST["txtNomAcademia"];

            $registrarProfesor = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_PROFESOR_INSERTAR('$idAcademia', '$nombre', '$numTel', '$cedula', '$correo', '$nomAcademia');");

        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Revisa que no hayan datos vacios</div>';
        }
    }

    CerrarBaseDatos($instancia);
}
```

Lo que pasa si lo hago así me va a insertar el nombre de la academia que seleccione el usuario y el Id que seleccione el usuario, por lo que quiero que cuando el usuario seleccione la academia "xxxx" se seleccione el id de esa academia y se digite en la base de datos.

Comment: Una opción seria por Ajax seria mas fácil y sin recargar la pagina. En tus funciones imprimes los select no estas retornando los valores, funciona así?, que error te marca?

Comment: Aún no lo he hecho porque no sé como implementarlo entonces no me marca ningun error. Si los select funcionan correctamente de esta forma, el primero es para tener el id en pantalla pero que no se vea, el segundo muestra las academias disponibles en la base de datos. La idea es que al seleccionar la academia se muestre el id en el select de los id para luego insertarlos en la base de datos, pero eso es lo que no he podido hacer.

Comment: No necesitas agregar otro **select**, en uno solo muestra el nombre, y en el value del select agregas el id de php ejemplo: **<option value="'. $item['ID_ACA'] .'">'. $item['NOMBRE_ACA'] .'</option>**, lo que envia el select es su **value** no el texto, al seleccionar una opocion eviara el **id** solamente.